# How to use customize Parse query to find whereKey: doesNotContainString:?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, parse-platform

Presently, I have a `Game` class table with an attribute named `currentTurnPlayer`. For a query, I am interested in getting all the `game` objects where `currentTurnPlayer`'s name does **not** equal to my `self.currentUser.username`

In other words, I am stuck on trying to do the opposite of what default Parse' [query method](http://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey%3acontainsString%3a) `whereKey:containsString:` does, and to only retrieve objects where the key does not contain the string `self.currentUser.username`.  How would I be able to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using PFQuery with your own predicate.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"currentTurnPlayer != %@",
                          self.currentUser.username];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:[Game parseClassName]
                                   predicate:predicate];
```

... and then execute the query as usual.

Parse doesn't support all predicate statements, but it supports the basic ones, including `==` and `!=`.

Comment: How is this different from whereKey:notEqualTo ?

Comment: @MariusFalkenbergWaldal you would have to use a different predicate such as MATCHES or LIKE for a partial string.

Answer (score 2):

Using `whereKey:notEqualTo:` should do the trick. However if you're not matching exact name to exact name (i.e. allowing the user to enter a search term), that obviously won't work.

In that case you'll want to use `whereKey:matchesRegex:` I'm not a regex pro but here's an example.

```
[query whereKey:@"currentTurnPlayer" matchesRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(?i:^.*%@.*$)", playerName]];
```